# PHP - "Payload too Large" error on retrieving webpage via curl

Tags: php, curl

This code works fine for the majority of webpages, but I have started receiving the "Payload too large" error when the webpage content is on the larger side.

I have increased the following PHP variables to their max with no luck: `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize`. I have also tweaked the apache variable `LimitRequestBody` to the max value also.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

/* Curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it. */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

rewind($verbose);
$verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);

echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>", htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "</pre>\n";*/

if (!curl_errno($ch)) 
{
    switch ($http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) 
    {
        case 200:  # OK
        break;
        default:
            echo 'Unexpected HTTP code: ', $http_code, "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your PHP is loading the configuration file you edit?

Comment: I printed out the config values before running this code, and they reflected the maximum's I edited them to.